# Usage of Session entities in user entity resolution of dialogflow

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

As dialogflow System entity for **GivenName** and **LastName** is locale specific , so I am populating session entity to supplement my user entity **PlayerFullName**.  **PlayerFullName** is a composite entity consisting of a combination of **System.GivenName** and **System.LastName**. Even though I see that session entity gets populated with the name that i provide at run time but dialog flow is not able to resolve the PlayerFullName entity with the data supplied.  Am i missing something or  my understaing of dialogflow session entity is not correct. Please help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please put some screenshot with examples, it will be easier to understand.